Use both revalidatePath and Return Value in Server Action?
Can someone help me
Description: I use useFormState with server action, but when i use both revalidatePath and return value, the revalidatePath work but doesn't return any value state for useFormState, when i remove revalidatePath, the returned value is received as normal, but i want to use both, any one can solve this?
I tried to remove one of two and it works perfect but not work using both, i want to use both of them
enter image description here

I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Having a loading template inside the root of the /app directory was causing the issue for me. Removing the loading templates resolved the issue.

This is solved the problem, but are there any answers to this problem? removing but still don't understand why it affect the server action

I have not been able to find a bug report about this issue but it is resolved in the latest canary nextjs release. I suspect it is related to nextjs creating a suspense boundary internally when the loading template is used triggering a re-render and losing the form state in the progress.

Thanks for your answer, that help me a lot.

this solutions works, confirmed still happen on nextJS 14.2.5. wanted to say lots of thanks, this is the most unpredictable behaviour which could waste lots of time to just figuring this out. to conclude: revalidatePath + return serverAction  + useFormState cannot be combine with Loading Router
